# Add checkboxcell programmatically to NSTableView

Tags: xcode, cocoa, checkbox, cell, nstableview

i am using the following code to add cells to a NSTableView. But this is adding textboxcells. i would need to add CheckboxCells instead. Could somebody please tell me how i can do that?

thanks!

```
//add cells
for (NSManagedObject *a in sortedArray)
{    
    NSTableColumn *newcolumn = [[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[a valueForKey:@"Name"]]];
    [[newcolumn headerCell] setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[a valueForKey:@"Name"]]];
    [newcolumn setWidth:50];

[table addTableColumn:newcolumn];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check box is implemented as a button. You simply set the dataCell property of NSTableColumn to indicate the default dataCell.

```
//add cells
for (NSManagedObject *a in sortedArray)
{    
    NSTableColumn *newcolumn = [[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[a valueForKey:@"Name"]]];
    [[newcolumn headerCell] setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[a valueForKey:@"Name"]]];
    [newcolumn setWidth:50];

    NSButtonCell * checkBox = [[NSButtonCell alloc] init];
    [checkBox setButtonType:NSSwitchButton];
    [newColumn setDataCell:checkBox];
    [table addTableColumn:newcolumn];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Quck simple clear and well explained! :)